# Is 讚 the preferred variant in traditional Chinese writing for "great/cool"?

Tags: traditional-characters

I noticed that on some Netflix TV shows they like to translate "great/cool" as:

> 讚、超讚，etc

in the traditional Chinese subtitles for shows.

It's funny to me because I tend to associate 赞 with thumbs up: , these days more than anything else, making the "speech" radical on 讚 all the more jarring.

Of course, historically 讚 can be associated with speech.

Is 讚 the preferred variant in traditional Chinese writing for "great/cool"?

Answer (score 1):

The use of 讚 (means 棒 in 閩南語/台灣話) to indicate good/great/excellent originally was limited to the Taiwanese whose native spoken language is 閩南語. With both the Mandarin (國語) and Taiwanese (台灣話) pronounce the word the same way, it has quickly gained popularity through TV shows and spread to the entire population of Taiwan.

Answer (score 0):

Update:
From the comment, the question is about the form of tradition form of "赞". So the below answer may have no help.

For great,I think yes.

For cool, I think no. We have "酷" for it.

Comment: No, the question is asking: is 讚 the proper tradition form of 赞?

Answer (score -2):

First make an announcement, I will answer using simplified chinese. When saying "cool" in daily use circumstance, it could be translated to "酷", I think "酷" is more oral than "赞". "酷" has similar pronounce with "cool" but has the same meaning while "赞" just has the same meaning not the pronounce.
"great" means better than good, "great" can be translated to "很棒","很赞","很好".

Comment: This does not answer the question.